# How to enable move to sd card option

Tags: android

The application is already in the playstore. After installation, in the application infos the option is disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` on your manifest file

 for more check also the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/data/install-location.html).